# How to find a peak and 2 valleys in my data?

Tags: r, plot, curve-fitting, smoothing, curve

[image]

Hi, I have a dataset (and relative plot) that look a bit like this (it's a series of measurements over time). As you can see, it's full of noise (and actually this has already been "smoothed" with a rolling average).

I am trying to achieve 2 things:

1. Find the first (and highest) peak and the 2 valleys around it. Only this one peak, not all peaks in the curve.
2. Fit a line from the 1st valley to the peak, and from the peak to the 2nd valley, see example below (I think I have an idea of how to do this, so it's less important)

[image]

I've tried some methods found online (like `find_peaks` from ggpmisc), but I've only been able to find **all** peaks and valleys, while I only need this specific one (that is the only true one).

Do you guys have any suggestions?

**EDIT**

If anyone's interested, I managed to do it by using `pracma::findpeaks` (it can also find valleys by putting a - sign before the variable of interest). I added TRUE/FALSE columns to track where peaks and valleys are to make it easier to plot these points later.

```
#Find peak
peaks <- findpeaks(data$L.MEAN, npeaks = 1, minpeakdistance = 100, sortstr = TRUE)
is_peak <- vector("logical" , length(data$Time))
data$is_peak = is_peak
for (Time in peaks[,2]) {
  data$is_peak[Time] = TRUE
}

#Find valleys
valleys <- findpeaks(-data$L.MEAN, npeaks = 2, minpeakdistance = 100)
is_valley <- vector("logical" , length(data$Time))
data$is_valley = is_valley
for (Time in valleys[,2]) {
  data$is_valley[Time] = TRUE
}
```

Comment: Why have you posted code for plotting when you're asking about analyzing data?

Comment: well peak can be easily found by `which.max()` then you can use the index to either step back or forward to find the end points of the valleys. a sample data included or a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll derive some data to analyze:

```r
dat <- data.frame(x = seq(-1, 6*pi, by=0.01))
dat$y <- sin(dat$x) / ifelse(abs(dat$x) < 1e-9, 1, sqrt(abs(dat$x)))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

[image: dampened sine wave]

Finding the max is easy with `which.max`:

```r
ymaxi <- which.max(dat$y)
ymaxi
# [1] 432
dat$y[ymaxi + -1:1]
# [1] 0.8512233 0.8512383 0.8511839

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point(data = ~ .[ymaxi,], color = "red")
```

[image: dampened sine wave, the max value highlighted with a red dot]

Finding the preceding/following valleys is a skosh more work

```r
ymini1 <- ymaxi + 1L - which(diff(rev(dat$y[1:ymaxi])) > 0)[1]
dat$y[ymini1 + -2:2]
# [1] -0.8511520 -0.8512284 -0.8512356 -0.8511732 -0.8510408
ymini2 <- which(diff(dat$y[-(1:ymaxi)]) > 0)[1] + ymaxi
dat$y[ymini2 + -1:1]
# [1] -0.4633072 -0.4633109 -0.4632688

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + geom_point(data = ~ .[c(ymini1, ymaxi, ymini2),], color = "red")
```

[image: same dampened sine wave with one peak and two surrounding valleys highlighted]

I'm defining "valley" as the point where the gradient (`diff(.)`) changes from negative to positive. You may need to include some tolerance with this, such that the change is held for so-many-points in order to skip false-valleys ... in which case there are a lot of various heuristics, mostly depending on the context of the data and your intent. For instance, you can find the most with a positive above a certain value, such as changing `> 0` to `> 0.01` or similar, but this can fail if it is positive (sloped-up) but very close to flat. Or you could say look for n-consecutive positives, which is a rolling window question and well-informed by using `zoo::rollapply` or `data.table::frollapply` or many other window functions; you could also use run-length-encoding for this (R's `rle` function), perhaps something like:

```r
diffs <- diff(dat$y[-(1:ymaxi)])
r <- rle(diffs > 0)
r
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:6] 343 318 316 315 315 160
#   values : logi [1:6] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
r$values[r$lengths < 3 & r$values] <- FALSE
which(inverse.rle(r))[1] + ymaxi
# [1] 776
```

which happens to be the same as above, but would "ignore" positive-gradients that are only 1 or 2 points before going negative again.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this! So, when I try and replicate your example it's only finding one valley (ymini2) but not the first one (ymini1). Not sure why! "dat$y[ymini1 + -2:2]" returns "[1] NA NA NA NA NA"

Comment: I have no idea.